# SpeechRecognition not importing in Pycharm even after installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, speech-recognition

I installed `SpeechRecognition` but its not showing.
I even saw that on web but nothing solved my prob.

```
import pyttsx3
import SpeechRecognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
```

[image: for reference]

Comment: Why not just use Pycharm itself to install `SpeechRecognition`. I find it so much easier. You can also quickly check all of your python installations.

Comment: i had done that also , it says package installed but its not imported

Comment: i use Pycharm for installation though but its not working in this one